# How to isolate rows in MySQL using MAX?

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following MySQL tables:

project:
pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum

works_on:
essn, pno, hours

My goal of this query is to return the project name and hours of the project(s) with the maximum amount of hours allocated to any project.

So far, I have

```
SELECT *, SUM(hours) as total_hours
FROM project p
    JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno
GROUP BY pname
```

which when executing gives the following:

[image]

I would like to isolate the entries with 55 hours allocated to it but I've tried

```
SELECT *, SUM(hours) as total_hours
FROM project p
    JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno
WHERE total_hours = MAX(total_hours)
GROUP BY pname
```

which gives me Error Code: 1054: Unknown column "total_hours" in "where clause"
which I know is clearly wrong but I'm not sure what other approaches I would take.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(w.hours) as total_hours,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(w.hours) DESC) drnk
    FROM project p
    JOIN works_on w ON p.pnumber = w.pno
    GROUP BY p.pname
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE drnk = 1;
```